# JSForce: Singleton or Connection or Pool

Tags: singleton, connection-pooling, jsforce

I'm using JSForce on my server that is accepting requests. As of now, a new connection is created on each JSForce request and then logged out once everything's all done. Am I going to encounter an issue with this methodology? Instead, does it make more sense to make a Singleton or a connection pool?

Comment: Good question! We are having the same doubt.

Comment: @EduardoMontoya Appreciate it! For now, I've just been initializing and tearing down connections whenever needed but will update the question if I discover anything on my end